# Restore and backup, mapped network drives without logging off

Tags: windows, batch, vbscript, network-drive

I use this script to restore and backup network drives

```
SET path=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\drives_backup.reg

C:\Windows\System32\reg.exe Export HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Network %path%
```

It work great but because I'm not using `net use` and am editing the registry, I have to make the user log off and sign in again for the changes to be applied. Is there any way to the same thing without having to log off the user?

I also a .vbs script that saves the mapped network drives to the following format

```
G: (\\path1\GROUPS)
```

but have no idea how to translate theses to

```
net use G: \\path1\GROUPS
```

Answer (score 1):

You can export the .reg file and then iterate through it and use that data with `net use`:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

SET _path=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Desktop\drives_backup.reg

C:\Windows\System32\reg.exe Export HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Network %_path%
for /f "tokens=1* delims=^=" %%a in ('type "%_path%"^|findstr /b .RemotePath') do (
    set network=%%~b
    set network=!network:\\=\!
    for /f "delims=[]" %%# in ('find /n %%b "%_path%"') do set n=%%#
    set /a n-=1
    for /f "delims=[] tokens=2" %%# in ('find /n /v "" "%_path%"^|findstr /b /c:"[!n!]"') do net use %%~n#: "!network!"
)
```

This script

- exports the .reg file to the path given
- reads the exported .reg file and looks for relevant lines
- for each network found executes `net use FOUNDDRIVELETTER: \\found\network`

If I understand correctly, the .reg file doesn't actually change often. Tell me if you'd like the "export .reg file" function to be separate/optional to the `net use` part.

Also, I strongly recommend you do not name variables "path".